# Boost program options, empty string handling

Tags: c++, boost, command-line, boost-program-options

I'm trying to port old command line tool to `boost::program_options`. The tool is used in lots of 3rd-party scripts, some of them I cannot update, so changing of command line interface (CLI) is not the way for me.

I have one positional argument, several flag and regular arguments. But I run into a trouble with `ranges` argument. It should work as follows:

```
> my_too.exe -ranges 1,2,4-7,4 some_file.txt    # args[ranges]="1,2,4-7,4"
> my_too.exe -ranges -other_param some_file.txt # args[ranges]=""
> my_too.exe -ranges some_file.txt              # args[ranges]=""
```

Basically, I want `boost::po` to stop parsing argument value if other argument is met or if type doesn't match. Is there a way to implement *exactly* this behavior?

I tried using `implicit_value` but it doesn't work because it will require CLI format change (argument is required to be adjusted with a key):

```
> my_too.exe -ranges="1,2-3,7" some_file.txt
```

I tried using `multitoken, zero_tokens` trick, but it doesn't stop when positional argument is met or argument doesn't match.

```
> my_tool.exe -ranges 1,2-4,7 some_file.txt # args[ranges]=1,2-4,7,some_file.txt
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not simple, but the syntax you require is weird and surely needs some hand tweaking is needed, e.g. the validator for `multitoken` syntax, to recognize "extra" argument.

I'll let myself start with the cool part:

```
./a.out 1st_positional --foo yes off false yes file.txt --bar 5 -- another positional
parsed foo values: 1, 0, 0, 1,
parsed bar values: 5
parsed positional values: 1st_positional, another, positional, file.txt,
```

So it seems to work even for a pretty weird combination of options. It also handled:

```
./a.out 1st_positional --foo --bar 5 -- another positional
./a.out 1st_positional --foo file.txt --bar 5 -- another positional
```

## The solution

You can manually tamper with recognized values after running the `command_line_parser`, before using `store`.

Below is a crude draft. It handles one extra token at the end of `--foo` `multitoken` option. It calls custom validation and moves last offending token to a positional argument. There are few caveats I described after the code. I have left some debug `cout`s intentionally so anyone can easily play with it.

So here is the [draft](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12213fe1b979cc87):

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/program_options/options_description.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options/parsers.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options/variables_map.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options/positional_options.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options/option.hpp>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace boost::program_options;

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// A helper function to simplify the main part.
template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const vector<T>& v)
{
    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<T>(os, ", ")); 
    return os;
}

bool validate_foo(const string& s)
{
    return s == "yes" || s == "no";
}

int main(int ac, char* av[])
{
    try {
        options_description desc("Allowed options");
        desc.add_options()
        ("help", "produce a help message")
        ("foo", value<std::vector<bool>>()->multitoken()->zero_tokens())
        ("bar", value<int>())
        ("positional", value<std::vector<string>>())
        ;

        positional_options_description p;
        p.add("positional", -1);

        variables_map vm;
        auto clp = command_line_parser(ac, av).positional(p).options(desc).run();

        // ---------- Crucial part -----------
        auto foo_itr = find_if( begin(clp.options), end(clp.options), [](const auto& opt) { return opt.string_key == string("foo"); });
        if ( foo_itr != end(clp.options) ) { 
            auto& foo_opt = *foo_itr;

            cout << foo_opt.string_key << '\n';
            std::cout << "foo values: " << foo_opt.value << '\n';

            if ( !validate_foo(foo_opt.value.back()) ) {                                        // [1]
                auto last_value = foo_opt.value.back(); //consider std::move
                foo_opt.value.pop_back();

                cout << "Last value of foo (`" << last_value << "`) seems wrong. Let's take care of it.\n";

                clp.options.emplace_back(string("positional"), vector<string>{last_value} );    // [2]
            }
        }
        // ~~~~~~~~~~ Crucial part ~~~~~~~~~~~~

        auto pos = find_if( begin(clp.options), end(clp.options), [](const auto& opt) { return opt.string_key == string("positional"); });
        if ( pos != end(clp.options)) {
            auto& pos_opt = *pos;
            cout << "positional pos_key: " << pos_opt.position_key << '\n';
            cout << "positional string_key: " << pos_opt.string_key << '\n';
            cout << "positional values: " << pos_opt.value << '\n';
            cout << "positional original_tokens: " << pos_opt.original_tokens << '\n';
        }

        store(clp, vm);
        notify(vm);

        if (vm.count("help")) {
            cout << desc;
        }
        if (vm.count("foo")) {
            cout << "parsed foo values: " 
                 << vm["foo"].as<vector<bool>>() << "\n";
        }
        if (vm.count("bar")) {
            cout << "parsed bar values: " 
                 << vm["bar"].as<int>() << "\n";
        }        
        if (vm.count("positional")) {
            cout << "parsed positional values: " <<
                vm["positional"].as< vector<string> >() << "\n";
        }
    }
    catch(exception& e) {
        cout << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

So the problems I see are:

1. Custom validation should be the same as the one used by parser for the option type. As you can see `program_options` is more permissive for `bool` than `validate_foo`. You can make last token `false` and it would be wrongly moved. I didn't know how to pull out the validator used for the option by the library so I supplied a crude custom version.
2. Adding an entry to `basic_parsed_options::option` is rather tricky. It basically messes with internal state of the object. As one can see I have made a rather rudimentary version, e.g. it copies `value`, but leaves `original_tokens` vector alone creating discrepancy in the data structure. Other fields are also left as-is.
3. Weird things might happen if you don't account for `positional` arguments present at other places in command line. That would mean `command_line_parser` would create one entry in `basic_parsed_options::option`, and the code would add another with the same `string_key`. I am not sure of consequences, but it does work with the weird example I used.

Resolving problem 1. could make it a nice solution. I guess other stuff is for diagnostics. (*Not 100% sure though!*). One could also identify offending tokens by other means, or in a loop.

You could just remove offending token and store them on side, but leaving this to `boost_options` still uses it's validation routines, which can be nice. (You can try changing `positional` to `value<std::vector<int>>()`)

Comment: It seems like post processing of parsing result, right? Would it be simpler to hack just `ac`/`av`?

Comment: How do you want to hack it? The only thing on top of regular `program_options` flow is the "crucial part" and if you remove debug, you have 5-10 lines. And essentially it is hacking `argc`, `argv`; done after boost tokenization.